# Website Parser in Javascript to get the author of images - CSV

Tags: javascript, parsing, csv, web

I got a list of about 1500 images with IDs from shutterstock and already tried this with VBA and macros. But I am not really into VBA, so maybe someone knows how to write this in JS?

I have CSV with the IDs and want to parse the website of shutterstock like 
[this](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic.mhtml?id=2166847) (i got the id in the csv "2166847")
And for this example I want to get the author "W14A" from the website and save it to the next column of the CSV (next to the ID-Column).

Or just generate a new CSV...

I am already trying to code it, but maybe someone know a simple fast solution?

Comment: show us what you have coded so far, we can't give you a solution, only help with problems in your solution

Comment: You can't using only client-side `JavaScript`. You will need some server-side code to get the content of the image's page.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do web scraping. Standard browser JavaScript will not be enough for that. You should have a look at browser extensions or automation (Selenium WebDriver maybe?)

Comment: Are you talking about WSH JScript implementation? Share please the fragment of the csv.